# How do time filter shortcuts work in KIbana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard, elastic-stack

Kibana provides time filter shortcuts like Today, Yesterday, last 10 days etc in the dashboard. I want to know how do they work. When I click Today in Kibana, Which field is used in the query? How can i configure these links to take custom timestamp fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your index the first time you choose after that Time filter field name: [image]

this filter will be used when you choose last 15 minutes or another time filter.

By default it is the timestamp but if you have a time field in your fields list you can use it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How do I arrive at this Configure settings?

Comment: On your kibana interface, there is management at the end. there you can choose the index and then the time filter